# Deleting duplicate lines based on a criteria on a file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a data file extracted from a table. Now I have to retain lines with latest timestamp for an id if there are multiple entries for the id if exist. 
  Need to delete other old entry lines. The file need to be cleaned up.

```
Id | timestamp | status
3 | 17-Feb-20 12:30:00:00 PM | E
1 | 16-feb-20 09:30:00:00 Am | L
3 | 17-Feb-20 15:30:00:00 PM | N
2 | 17-Feb-20 10:12:00:00 Am | L
```

My need is I need to retain id 1,2 as there are only one entry. But id 3 has two rows but should retain the one with timestamp 15:30 PM since that's the latest.

I got reference to use 'sed' cmd to delete particular line number or particular line. But the thing is I will be reading line by line.
   Say on looping first line wud be id 3, I wud grep on the same file for matching id if exist. So for id 3 I got naother match, then will compare the timestamp. Since the current line I'm on is older timestamp need to delete tat line and retain latest one. 
   Is it possible to do the operation on the same file which I will be reading through or should obviously go with another file ??

Comment: Could you please do add 3 simple things in your post. 1- sample of input, 2- sample of output and 3rd- your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Is your file always sorted so that later timestamps are after earlier ones for a given id?

Comment: Is it required that the order of the output lines corresponds to the order of the input? In your example, do you need the output to be in the order of IDs 1, 3, 2 or can it be in any order, e.g. IDS 1, 2, 3 or 3, 1, 2?

Comment: 1.Data not sorted in any orderly fashion. It extracts table data.                                                    2. Ordering not expected but should be unique.

Comment: This should be done directly in the SQL, much simpler!